# Error while running the Cron Drupal 6.18

Tags: drupal, search, drupal-6, cron

I have a site that is in Drupal 6.18. It has been developed by other developer.
There are a lot of issues in the site, one of which is, when I try to Run the Cron it gives me following error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function real_escape_string() in somepath\common.inc(1699) : eval()'d code on line 3

I have checked the common.inc(1699) and there is nothing fishy :(
It goes to function drupal_eval($code).

I did a bit of a research and found that the real_escape_string() is used by mysql or mysqli class. These libraries are enabled in my php.ini

Please let me know where should i look to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't in common.inc, it is in some custom PHP code written somewhere such as [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules), [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views), a node, block, etc.  Fix (or remove) that code and you should see some results.

Comment: +1, My guess is there is something hackish going here and it could even be some raw MySQL code in one of those areas as well. He should also check the logs, it might give more insight as to where the error is occurring. It could even be some code in the site's theme files as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, there is a lot of hacks applied in the code. Will check for things you have mentioned get back if needed.

Comment: You guys were very right!! I found out code written in the body of few page nodes...Here is how I found out the issue:
1. Use **PHPMyadmin** and its "Search in entire database" feature to find the function having issue(in my case "real_escape_string")
2. I found them in node revisions table, you can the update the functions as per your wish and get the site working